# How to count total number of columns in a mongodb table

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

So I'm wondering if it's possible to count the total of columns in a mongodb table by the use of .pug? How can I add the total number of columns automatically to a .pug file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be possible in the frontend side 
but we can do it from the backend like below one

```
let dbColumnCount = Object.keys( await db.collectionName.find().lean() ).length;

res.send({dbColumnCount});
```

Comment: So if I add that on the backend side of stuff, what would I add to the frontend side? Something like ($columntotal) or anything?

Comment: _i don't think so and I don't have enough knowledge in pug,
usually in ejs we send data values to file like this < res.render(filename,data) >
it will work ,you can prefer this how to pass dynamic values from the backend  to pug files_ [pug link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)